# Why is my army weaker than computer's army?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I (Castille) have 31000 men in my army (20 regiments of infantry and 11 of cavalry). Computer (Aragon) has 21000. During the battle I can see how much damage each one is producing. Every attack from them damages me 300 to 500. I only damage them 7 to 15.

Why is this happening? My men have high morale. I'm in my own territory. By the end of many battles I went from 31000 to 15000 and they only lost 3000 men and even regained their forces faster than me.

So pretty much I want to understand what I'm doing wrong and what exactly do I need to do to have a successful army. Also if someone can give me some pointers on the game overall.

Comment: Sorry for the 3 year necro comment, but I find this is a common problem for new players who often start as Castile: Aragon starts with a very good 2 star general, while Castile starts with a weak general. Combine that with the terrain and crossings and you're likely to get your butt whooped if you attack Aragon early.

Answer (score 7):

This site doesn't give overall pointers, but I can explain why you might be losing with superior numbers.
There are a couple reasons that this could be happening. They could have better military tech than you. I doubt this is the case since it sounds like you are talking about early game and you shouldn't fall far behind aragon in general. They could have better leaders than you, make sure you assigned a leader. They could be simply very lucky, although this is unlikely with armies as big as the ones you mentioned. They may have a better army composition than you (50 percent inf/cav and 50 percent artillery is stronger than 100 percent inf/cav).

If you are the attacker, you also could be penalized for crossing a river, attacking into mountains or desert, or winter.

If you post a couple screenshots of the battle overview (the box that shows the troop formations and penalties and leader bonuses) I can probably explain the exact problem for you.

Comment: and then there's terrain penalties (mountains, rivers, weather) affecting the attacker different from the defender.

Comment: @jwenting I thought he was the defender. Rereading it, looks like that is not in fact specified to be the case

Comment: even if he's the defender, he might still suffer penalties. Not sure if EUIV implements that, but I've seen games where say defending a low lying area gives you a disadvantage.

Comment: @jwenting I'm pretty sure its not the case in EU4. I guess I would have to try fighting in marsh to be certain though

Comment: I have not seen any indication of defender's receiving penalties yet. This is more than likely the result of poor rolls and a difference in leader abilities and tactics.

Comment: If it's mountainous and you have cavalry, I think the cavalry takes a penalty to attacking.